# The new "Duplicate" close restrictions don't allow for closure of double posts

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

One of the recent changes to closing questions makes it so that you can't close something as a dupe of something else unless the original has answers.

This is a problem when a user posts a question, gets no response, and then posts the same thing a few hours later.

It's certainly a good idea to keep a well meaning user from being sent to a black hole with no help, but this behavior breaks the ability for non-moderators to deal with double posts.

Please allow people to cast "close as duplicate" votes regardless of the number of answers a post has if the OP is the same for both questions.

Answer (score 5):

From [an official response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/186381): (emphasis mine)

> There are some exceptions to the requirement that the original have answers. First, mods can close as dupe of anything, to handle any special cases. Second, **you can always close as dupe if it's from the same user, to cover the case of problem users who post the same thing multiple times.** Last but not least, this check is disabled on meta.

Comment: Yep, my bad. Carry on, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 0):

If a user does post the same question (or a substantially identical question) you should probably:

1. Leave a comment *politely* explaining that patience is a virtue, and inviting them to improve their original question (if applicable)
2. Flag it so the <s>janitorial staff</s> mods can zot or merge the duplicate

Close-as-Duplicate is the big orange DETOUR sign of Stack Exchange.
Question merges are the nice new paved interstate Dot has been promising to build for 10 years.