# Should there be a better balancing system for voting to mark a question as a duplicate?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

It seems that many of my own questions have been closed simply because I misworded them and they assumed it was a duplicate question. Indeed, sometimes there was a duplicate question with an answer I could use, but many times, there was simply a miscommunication and my situation was indeed unique. However, I then come back to check on the answers to find *no* answers or comments, and the question had been closed.

**Would it not be reasonable to require an asker to give their reasoning before marking their question as a duplicate, or to deal out a negative rep for voting to close a question?** I'm not saying that no question deserves to be closed, as I've done my share of close voting, but many don't deserve to, and once one person votes to close, it seems that every next person that sees the question also votes and it's closed without even asking the original poster if the other question indeed helps them.

Comment: There is a lot of history to the way things are now. Putting an obstacle to closing means that many questions that _should_ be closed will not be. We also used to have a reputation penalty for downvoting questions which has gone away for the same reason.

Comment: _"I then come back to check on the answers to find no answers or comments, and the question had been closed"_ How long does it take you to come back? If you're asking a question and disappearing you can hardly complain that this happens behind your back. Keep checking, every minute for the first 30 or so and then regularly thereafter so that you can answer any comments asking for clarification or to explain why your question is not a duplicate.#

Comment: _"It seems that many of my own questions have been closed simply because I misworded them"_; if this is happen regularly you should consider whether you should change _how_ you ask questions. If you're constantly being misinterpreted it would seem like you should modify _your_ behaviour rather than the site its.

Comment: Closing does require selecting a reason. If you mean they should have to type their own message, you should take a look at [this question from yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176676/get-rid-of-canned-messages-for-closings) on that topic.

Comment: @Oded according to http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation, the downvote reputation penalty still exists.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards less than a day, usually.

Comment: @Supuhstar - Yes. To the asker of the question. Not the caster of the downvote.

Comment: @suphstar: there is a downvote penalty (to the caster) on *answers*, not on questions.

Comment: @DavidRobinson ah, I see.

Comment: @DavidRobinson ... doesn't that mean I can just go around -1ing every question I see because they're not about invisible pink flying unicorns?

Comment: @Supuhstar: Do you feel like you want to?

Comment: @Supuhstar, a day is _far_ too long for your first check to see whether you've got any answers. Most questions get answered inside 10 minutes. You have to stay around and answer comments otherwise people will just close your question if it's difficult to understand.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards That's not my fault, but theirs. They're working in an instant-satisfaction mentality, when the reality is that I have school and work taking up almost all my time. I can only check so many sites at a time before I have to do more important things, and because my boss wants me working and professors want me listening shouldn't mean that my question is closed due to impatience.

Comment: -1 because I didn't read the question I just joined the bandwagon of downvoters!

Comment: @supuhstar: if every poor question were left open for a full day to wait for the sender to get back, the site would become impossible to maintain. Answerers and reviewers pay much more attention to new questions, and that's not going to change (it's one of the greatest qualities of the site). Furthermore, you're talking about respecting the value of your time. Have you considered respecting the value of the time of the answerers, who are *giving it up for free* just to help you?

Comment: You wouldn't go to the bank to talk to your loan officer if you have class in ten minutes. Likewise, you should set aside a small chunk of time to post and keep an eye on your question on SO; it doesn't have to occupy your full attention, but you should be checking in a least half a dozen times in the first hour, especially during the more active periods of the day (late morning/early afternoon in each of Western Europe, SE Asia, and mainland U.S.A.). The high response rate here is a _feature_; it's not quite the same as a forum, and I think you'll come to like it if you give it a chance.

Comment: *"That's not my fault, but theirs. They're working in an instant-satisfaction mentality"*  Nope. That Stack Overflow generates good answers to good questions ***fast*** is a decidedly a feature and not a bug. For that matter, that it closes bad question fast is *also* a feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closing is not the end of the world. Unlike forum closings, "closed" on SE means "temporarily put on hold till the question is fixed".

Is something misworded? Fix it and flag for reopening. Is your post not a duplicate? Make that clear by editing.

Don't look at a closed question and feel "Oh, great! They destroyed my post." Think "Oh look, they closed it till it gets fixed! That way I won't get answers that misinterpret my question!" and then fix it by following the advice in the comments.

Of course, there are some closed questions that aren't fixable, but that's a different story.

Comment: True, but I feel like not many people look back over a question that's been closed. I think they'll see it and think "Oh, the asker didn't know what they were talking about. Guess I should go back and continue searching" or something like that.

Comment: @Supuhstar: The moment you make an edit, the post is added to a reopen queue where people review it. And you can always custom flag "I have fixed the issues, please reopen."

Comment: I see... It still feels, to me, much too easy to close a question, and too easy for a close cascade (voting to close because someone else did) to occur

Comment: @Supuhstar: So? It's reversible. Think something went wrong? Custom flag.