# "Leave a comment for the author" dialog on NC and NARQ closures

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, review, vote-to-close

We already know that [there is a problem with closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171732/205264). Whilst many closed questions are potentially *good*, only a few get reopened.

When I review low quality posts, I can "leave a comment for the author" to explain why we don't like link-only answers or why we don't want new questions as answers.

I think it might be a good idea to add such a "leave a comment for the author" dialog after the close vote dialog. Options could include:

- No comment needed (for site trolls, posts that can hardly be improved or when someone else left a comment already)
- We're missing sufficient information here, like code, .... Please add it to your question.
- This question is *overly broad*, please ask a sufficient question instead.
- ...

**This way, you can specify why exactly a question was closed, because the closure reasons are only collections of specific reasons.**

Every comment could go with a link to the FAQ as well, if you ask me.

Also, these comments could be different for the various closure reasons. For example, a not-constructive post should get other comments than a NARQ. For some closure reasons we don't need such a box: the duplicate system already has an auto-comment, the off-topic is very clear already and also the too-localized seems clear to me. It's most important for not-constructive and NARQ, I think.

Yes, we close way more often than we review low quality posts. Wouldn't the comments dialog get annoying? Perhaps, yes. If so, you could also display the comments dialog for the 5<sup>th</sup> closer only.

What would you think of this?
Any ideas for other comment options?

Answer (score 4):

Technically the close banner *is* this comment. I agree that the current banner could be improved or branched out to be more specific.

The current close system [is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv) [being](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d) [improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op), I think that these improvements cover this feature request adequately (specifically the branching out of NARQ and NC).

Comment: I think the close banner isn't specific enough: "This way, you can specify why exactly a question was closed, because the closure reasons are only collections of specific reasons." But yes, the system is being improved and that's a good thing.

Comment: @CamilStaps: Well, I was talking in the context of the upcoming improvements.

Comment: You mean a) letting the closers choose the close banner or b) just improving the banner or c) adding closure reasons with other banners or d) something else? :)

Comment: @CamilStaps: The close reasons are being branched out: so there will be "vague", "incomplete", "not a question", etc under NARQ with specific details. So the CVer gets to choose from these.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes that's a solution to the same problem :)