# Help center for closed questions is/will-be outdated

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, help, help-center

Since the "brand new, consolidated" help center has already been out on all sites in Stack Exchange network since [June 5, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/212576), and the new closing reasons are about to be launched [this week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/212576), I'd like to point out that the Closed Questions section in help-center is for the older UI and should be updated as soon as the closing reasons are rolled out to other sites.

The current [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) lists the following close reasons (on all sites):

- exact duplicate
- off topic
- not constructive
- not a real question
- too localized

But the new close reasons/UI is as follows:

[image]

where, "[off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op)" and "[unclear what you're asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv)" are further branched.

I think that the help-center about Asking can use the same text as in the featured post announcing [new closing reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/212576).

Comment: It will also have to mention "on hold" when the changes go live.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a draft of the new article already waiting for the new close reasons to go live everywhere. As soon as we turn the new close reasons on across the network, the page about closed questions will be updated.

Comment: Anywhere still not live? Time to update!

Comment: Updated for all sites