# Migrate <belongs on another site> from <off-topic> to the top-level of close reasons?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, close-reasons, off-topic

I understand that close reasons are supposed to be as [clear as possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169814/212773) to the OP, whilst simultaneously not overburdening the person suggesting the close with too much navigation through multiple close reason pages.

So at present to suggest moving to another site I click:

> Close > Off-topic > Belongs on another site > pick site > Sharepoint!

**BUT** (!) frequently the list does not contain the site most suited to migrate to (how many questions get migrated to meta nowadays out of interest?). Is it really too much to ask that people asking/answering questions on this site click a button marked other at the bottom of the site list to be taken to a full list of sites? If this is too much, can the migrate option be moved to the top level of close reasons so that this extra step does not obfuscate the close issue? So the process would become:

> Close >  Belongs on another site > Pick site > Other site > The right site

I personally find  it incredibly frustrating that sites such as Cross Validated are not on the list, despite having ~23k questions whilst both Database Administrators which has been running for 6 months longer than Cross Validated, has only ~ 15k questions and Sharepoint (?!) also has around 26k questions (but has also been active for 6 months longer). I believe the off-topic list *could* be more flexible and that would give the best directions to OPs about where their question belongs.

I think that as there is a certain barrier to entry to get anything out of the site (the ability to ask a well-formed question or the knowledge to answer it) that this increased flexibility would in no way make the site worse. I do admit I come from the data domain side of things (so Cross Validated would be *very* useful to have) and users from other disciplines may vehemently disagree with me, but I hope I have made a clear case for offering increased flexibility in the site migration options.

Comment: Woah, I'm tempted to downvote this just for your blatant abuse of formatting. The tag syntax *is for actual tags*, it does more than just change the visual appearance. And of course, inline code formatting is for code.

Comment: @CodyGray I know, I couldn't think of a better way to highlight it that's all. Sorry for the abuse!

Comment: Why do random words need to be highlighted at all? Can't we just read it?

Comment: And even if random words needed highlighting, have you considered normal and century old emphasising techniques such as **bold** and *italics*?

Comment: And quoting an entire line with a preceeding `>` is also useful when you have a sentence or paragraph that needs to standout.  But don't overuse that either.

Comment: @Bart I don't see this as a duplicate because it's a feature request. And thank you for reformatting appropriately.

Comment: There...fixed it. Now don't do that again please. You won't like me when you do that again....because I....well....I'd probably edit it again....

Comment: There are like 9,000 of these feature requests for specific sites. They've all been declined for the same couple of reasons: (1) overcomplicating the UI and violating "don't make me think", (2) it's *hard* to know when and where to migrate a question, so we only unlock the most common paths.

Comment: Long story short @SimonO101: we suck at migrating. That's why there are only a few. They are (afaik) based on the percentage of successful migrations. Allowing users to choose would result in a migration of crap, unfortunately.

Comment: @Bart understood! Sorry everyone for abusive formatting. Can we forget about the bad start now and discuss the issue. This is similar to the linked questions, but my suggestion is unique (as far as I could tell).

Comment: @SimonO101 how is it unique?  You want a list of all sites that the user can pick from) to migrate a question

Comment: @psubsee2003 because I suggest to migrate **move to another site** to the top level of close reasons. Did you read the question?

Comment: @SimonO101 If that is the core of your proposal, then remove your entire discussion on adding additional sites to the list or allowing for the selection of all sites.

Comment: @Bart no, because the point is we want additional sites. The 9000 or so feature requests for this (according to Cody) tell you I am not the only one! If you say its too complicated to have additional sites in the current framework, then lets think about changing the framework? Time to start trusting your users?

Comment: @SimonO101 No, because the statistics tell us otherwise. It's not too complicated. It's that users collectively suck at migrating. And it also means the dupe votes here are correct. No need to have the discussion again.

Comment: @Bart so once upon a time users were free to suggest migration to whatever site they liked?

Comment: @SimonO101 Yes I did read your post, but I agree with Bart.  One sentence asking to move the migration link to the top of the close list doesn't change the fact that 90% of the request is about migration to any site.  You have separate requests so unless you want one of the requests lost in the discussion of the other, you should make separate requests.

Comment: @SimonO101 but the reason for the duplicate is to try to group posts/discussion about specific features or bugs under the same post so you don't have 9000 open feature requests for the same thing.  If you feel that strongly, then I suggest providing a strong argument as an answer to the duplicate and/or add a bounty to that post.  Don't let the status-declined tag scare you, IIRC there have been some recent feature requests that were implemented that were previously declined

Comment: @psubsee2003 thank you for the clarification. The title of the question is about migrating the site list to the top of close reasons so I'd hoped this would make it clear.

Comment: +1 I have quite a few times abstained from voting to migrate because the whole process is way to cumbersome if you cannot use the predefined options. It might be useful to have tag specific targets.

Comment: @Bart the result of all this is that even though I *want* to help keep the site clean, relevant and free of crap that shouldn't be on it, I won't because I don't have the easily accessible tools to so. I think that is a real shame.

Comment: @SimonO101 like Bart said, if that is really what you want, then I suggest removing the migrate to any site part from this post, or remove the top level request from this post and make another post.

Comment: Questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17834448/1478381) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17831267/1478381) which have both appeared in the last hour. No-one is flagging these posts for migration because the correct option is not available (actually the correct option in these cases could be closure due to poor quality!).

Comment: @SimonO101 I actually agree, the migrate anywhere feature would be nice to have.  The problem is, as a collective whole, the community sucks are migrating questions.  Someone would see a networking question and say "this should be migrated to Server Fault" without knowing what Server Fault is all about.  Then 4 others would see the vote for migration and also vote the same.  Then it leaves the other site to have to clean up the crap coming from SO that doesn't really belong.  And most SE sites do not have substantial enough community moderation to deal with the volume.

Comment: @SimonO101 if you can find a good way to deal with that issue, then you might have a workable solution.

Comment: Couldn't the UI be improved such that i) I decide a Q is OT and should be migrated, ii) click that option in Close, iii) notice that it isn't on the list but there is an **Other** button/option, which when selected uses the same UI for *flagging* the post but simplified to just the Other part of the flag UI box? As of now I am voting to close as OT **and** flagging the post, which seems redundant...

Comment: @Simon That's *exactly* why we don't allow migration to any site. Because people would vote to migrate questions like those you linked. They should be closed outright instead. The cardinal rule of migration is **don't migrate crap**. Too much crap gets migrated if we unlock all the paths.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256149/can-we-streamline-migration-for-moderators was asked specifically for moderators (who can migrate anywhere), but I bring it up because if you make "migrate anywhere" available to a broader group of users you'll also need to deal with that, or risk an increase in bad migrations.