# Can we streamline migration for moderators?

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-tools

As a moderator I sometimes get a request (flag, comment, chat ping, etc) to migrate a question.  Sometimes I don't know the other site's scope well enough, so what usually happens is the following:

- Open a new browser tab and go find that site.
- Click on the Help Center link.
- Click on the "what can I ask here?" link.
- Look for the on- and off-topic lists there. Read and decide.
- Close that tab and go handle the request.

Could we short-circuit some of these intermediate steps?  Something like this in the close dialogue, perhaps:

[image: migration dialogue]

Clicking that button -- or skip having the button and just do this when selecting a site (h/t animuson♦) -- would insert the contents of the other site's on-topic page into the dialogue window (with a scroll bar, obviously), similarly to how candidate duplicates are shown.  There's already room, even, so we don't need to make the dialogue box bigger.  If I then choose another site, then it should automatically switch to showing the new site's info.  (If I'm groping around for a site I probably need this information, after all.)  If there's nothing to show (e.g. for a per-site meta), then nothing changes.

A lot of times moderators instead just look for a moderator on the other site to ask.  That can be inefficient, and we've been told not to do that.  Can we make it easier for us all to RTFM and maybe cut down on that?

Comment: You don't even really need a button. Just select like normal and, upon selection, have a box below auto-populate with the relevant information for you to verify. Kind of like how the duplicate box works.

Comment: @animuson you're totally right -- even better!

Comment: I'd even go a step further, havin the same stuff for "user's VTC" – of course, only for the sites configured there. Might help preventing some "wrong selections" already at that point.