# Why don't we migrate more?

Tags: discussion, migration

So today, I asked a question on [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) and received the following [comment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/92708/why-does-a-copyright-on-a-website-include#comment148586_92708) about this being a legal issue and not being allowed on UX. Why wasn't this post migrated to the *Legal Stack Exchange*? **How do you migrate and why isn't it done more?**

Comment: Being a legal issue doesn't automatically mean it belongs on [law.se] - they have a help center that tells you what is and is not on topic there.

Comment: Could we encourage users to at least bring up migration? Most just say this is off topic and leave!

Comment: Why migrate to somewhere if it will be off-topic there? Unless you *know* the target site well, you shouldn't offer migration to it.

Comment: Migrations come in with the close privilege - you can vote to migrate to another site. You need a consensus on that (IIRC, 4 votes to the same destination) and a site can have a maximum of 5 destinations (their meta being one).

Answer (score 11):

One comment saying a question should be migrated doesn't mean it should be.  People say and think all sorts of things; they aren't always right.  Others on your site might disagree, or it might *sound* plausible but it turns out the other site has guidelines that the question doesn't satisfy.  If a question gets migrated in that state it'll just be closed on the other site.  All that bouncing around is frustrating for the user who asked the question, and we shouldn't be yanking the question around unnecessarily.

Migration is part of the close-vote process currently, so if voters (or a moderator) agree it will be migrated.  But if the question is *on-topic* where it was asked it shouldn't be migrated even if people think it would fit better somewhere else; if it's on-topic here, answer it here.

You as the *asker* can re-ask your question on another site if you agree with the suggestion, though this is a little controversial and you need to avoid crossposting the same question on multiple sites.  In re-asking you'll probably need to do some editing to tailor it for the site where you're asking it, so check out the site's tour and on-topic help.  If you re-ask your question elsewhere and can't just delete the original, be sure to indicate that you've done this -- a comment with a link to the new question, for example.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to re-ask a question elsewhere on the network. If the *OP* wants their question migrated, it's better if they flag it for moderator attention and request migration to a specific target site. (I know, I know, I don't have any diamond now, but I argued the same when I did. Except perhaps on the largest sites, this should be a rare enough event to not put any undue workload on the diamond moderators, and the largest sites on the network already have a good number of diamond moderators to spread the workload.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think, by and large, migrations haven't served us well; often I see a question get migrated that then has to be edited to fit the new site *anyway*, plus it comes with comments that usually need to be deleted, plus the user might not have even created an account so can't be pinged.  So if it hadn't gotten very far along to begin with, why not just start clean?  I made some minor edits to acknowledge that not all agree with this approach.

Comment: True, it depends on the specifics of the question being discussed. But I still think encouraging the user to post it a second time risks, if nothing else, leading to duplicated effort; the few times I've seen that, the OP has just reposted what they had, so we might almost *as well* just have migrated. If the question is poorly written, it might well be better to put it on hold on the original site, get it fixed up to a presentable state, *then* migrate.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling fixing a question before migrating it is good practice but too-seldom done.  IMO [migration should be possible only after closing, and we need to make the other site's scope more obvious to migraters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277891/162102).  Reducing bad migrations helps everybody.