# Better way to flag questions for "I want something for free"

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

while using SO and similar communities I often have seen questions like "I need something and here are my requirements, so please do it for me" or similar.

While reviewing First Posts I have found another question like that and want to share my opinion about it.

[image]

In general I don't like questions like that, because the user should show some tries or effort to get out of the situation and not asking other people doing it.
SO isn't the right place for jobs.

But I am missing some "good" reason for that:

[image]

Finally I selected the red marked reason, but I don't think it is the best option.

I have tried to find something similar here on meta, but only found a question to the close reason rework project ([Help us make "Off-Topic" close reasons clearer to the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169814/164124)).

Furtermore I would say that such questions should be deleted instead of just closed.

Comment: That looks like the correct close reason for the example you gave.

Comment: Hum ... perhaps we can rephrase it a little bit to match job offers?

Comment: I don't think that's really a job offer.  Those are rare enough that you can just flag them as Other -> "Job Offer" and they'll be closed/deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Are you talking about the cases where the OP lists a bunch of requirements with no effort and the initial reaction is "you should hire a contractor"? I see plenty of those but don't think this particular example fits that category.

Comment: My reaction would be like that, he has a html version and want a wordpress version. :)

Comment: Related: [What happened to the "you're just lazy" close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216491)

Comment: Your close reason is fine. You could also close this one as "unclear what you're asking" because there is no question in this question. A list of requirements is not a *question*. A description of how urgent a problem it is for the OP is not a *question*. But regardless, don't feel that you have to find the ideal reason to close a question. Vote to close, move on. And yes, such questions should be deleted, and will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions that are poorly researched, don't demonstrate effort in either an attempt to solve the problem, or in creating the question, can be downvoted.

In this specific case, yes, the user is asking for a recommendation for a product, so the close reason you highlighted is appropriate here.

Comment: How I wrote to Bill the Lizard's comment, perhaps there is a way to rephrase it to match job offers.

Comment: @CSchulz What do you mean by job offers?  I'm not seeing how you're getting "please come work for my company" out of that question, which is what I'd imagine a job offer in a question would be.

Comment: When I read his question, I would say he want something to be done (for free).

Comment: @CSchulz: well would that mean you're asking for something like a "minimal effort" close reason?

Comment: @CSchulz It looks more like a product request to me.  Asking someone to do work for you does not merit closure.  As I say in my answer, it can warrant a downvote if you feel there is insufficient effort on the part of the author.  The listed reason certainly doesn't qualify for all questions that lack sufficient effort, even though it does apply to this one question for entirely unrelated reasons.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps job offer is the wrong term. I mean doing work for someone who is too lazy to do it on his own or don't want to spend some money in professionals.

Comment: @CSchulz And I answered that with my first paragraph, and again in comments.