# Guidelines for creating a custom off-topic close-vote reason

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic

**Background:** My main site, CogSci.SE is going through a major overhaul to try and get it out of beta hell. One of the ways we are attempting this is creating a [new custom off-topic close vote reason](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2130/4397).

**Question:** Are there guidelines for creating a custom off-topic close reason? I know [there was a previous initiative to address this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op), as well in this question, but I figured this was worth being brought up again and rephrased because:

1. This would be a good FAQ for many sites starting up.
2. The linked question is old and it would be good to amalgamate the insights gained since that time. Also, the range of StackExchange sites has increased considerably since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I've been able to determine from various articles and my own experiences.

### [Be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Instead of slamming a door in OP's face, try to make OP understand that you want to help them. Adding the word "please" can go a long way.

### Be clear on what the OP can do to fix their question

Give the OP actionable suggestions for improving their question, so that they don't feel helpless and frustrated.

### Be brief in the reason and elaborate in a FAQ

The close vote reason should be brief enough for an outsider and the OP to understand in a broad sense why the question was deemed inappropriate for the site. The FAQ post should be detailed enough for an outsider and the OP to know how to avoid asking further questions of this type or how to improve their existing question.

### Keep the reason distinct from other close vote reasons

Make sure the new close vote reason is not just a rephrasing of the existing ones, such as "unclear what you're asking" and "too broad".