# Is there any way to post further question over an existing question in Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, site-usage

I have exactly the same question like this:

[Playing a stream of video data using QTKit on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854505/playing-a-stream-of-video-data-using-qtkit-on-mac-os-x)

However, there is no helpful answer for it.

In Stackoverflow, we cannot send message to someone priviately. But neither publicly.

Is there any way that I can ask the people who ask the question for his later progress on the question?

Comment: There is a public message system: simply comment on the question. Even better: improve the question with editing (but don't change the meaning!) and possibly add a bounty to it.

Comment: Since you don't have enough reputation on SO to comment on the posts, I'd suggest you either ask a new question or wait till your rep. increases so that you can [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you earn enough reputation (50), you'll earn the privilege to be able to leave comments on questions other than your own.  At that point, you can leave a comment on that question and ask if he solved his problem.

However, because of the [changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) to the duplicate system in the last couple of months, a question now only qualifies as a duplicate if there are answers and those answers address the problem.  Since there is not a quality answer to this question, I would say reasking your question would be open game.

If you do ask the question, I would not copy it word for word, but try to explain the situation in your own words, but it would also be helpful to link to that question and explain why that answer doesn't work.

And the 3rd option is a bounty.  You can put a bounty on that question to see about attracting more answers, but similar to the comments, you need a minimum reputation (75) for that.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it is a long time for a rookie to earn enough reputation on Stackoverflow.

Comment: 50 and 75 rep aren't too hard... 50 just takes 10 upvotes on questions or 5 upvotes on answers.  75 takes 15 and 8 respectively.  It is just a matter of being patient.

Comment: I am now with 6 reputations only. And that keep me away from upvoting. I should make hard to 15 hehe.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least 50 reputation, you can comment on a post. The OP will be notified because of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Leave comments to ask for further progress.User get a notification for it.If He/she interested to give you further progress you got it via comment or may be his own ans.