# Please put answers underneath questions in Close review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Many times when going through the Close queue I see that people are using the *too localized* reason.  Sometimes the reason for this is in the comments (like the syntax error being pointed out), but a lot of times it's in the answer, so then I have to click on the question and look at the answers to see if it is really *too localized*.

Could we please get the answers shown underneath the question in the Close review queue?

Comment: I don't think they should be expanded by default (or maybe only one expanded by default), but I'd like an easy way to import the answers into the same review screen rather than opening another window/tab.

Comment: Would be even more valuable for the Late Answers queue - very often these are duplicates of existing answers.

Comment: It'd be nice to get an official response to this.

Comment: This is already designed and is scheduled as part of our ongoing [review queues ux](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346902/51)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Review Queue [visual design changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues) we launched in Feb 2021, we now include an easy way to view all the answers to a question. It is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Answer (score 20):

I'd very much like to see this done, at least for questions with suggested duplicates.

Why do I want this?  Well, the [notice placed on questions closed as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) looks like this:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [Link to duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue)   *n+1 answers*

The way I see it, if the closed question already has answers, there is, or at least should be, an implied "better" there.  **There's no point in closing a question with a *great* answer as a duplicate of one with merely a *decent* answer.**  In fact, doing so is actively counterproductive, since it directs visitors to the less well answered question.

Currently, if a question in the duplicate close vote review queue already has answers, the only way to see them is to open it in a new tab.  To add insult to injury, the tabs showing the suggested duplicate questions *do* include their answers; it's only the answers to the question under review that can't be seen through the review interface.

Anyway, I was going to make a separate feature request for this, but I figure this one is close enough, so I'll just put a bounty on it to give it a bit more visibility.

**Ps.** Since the extra attention I was hoping for doesn't seem to have materialized, and since I can't award the bounty back to myself, does anybody want +200 rep as a Christmas present?  Just post an answer... ;-)

---

**Update:** [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.10 now contains a client-side implementation of this feature.  It works by detecting the presence of un-displayed answers (based on the summary table) and loading them via AJAX instead.  There's some kluginess involved in reformatting the answer wrapper elements to fit the review page format, but overall it seems to work nice and smoothly.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Meta bounties never seem particularly effective, which is a shame

Answer (score 2):

I recently asked the question: [Do "too broad" questions become less broad after an acceptable answer is given?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223454/do-too-broad-questions-become-less-broad-after-an-acceptable-answer-is-given)

There seemed to be a consensus that the existence of an answer added more information to the question, and that this information was useful in deciding if a question should be closed or not.

In particular, in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/230261), shog9 wrote:

> But when you're viewing an *answered* question, you have additional
>   data: **is the answer (or answers) complete?** Do they satisfy the
>   asker and stand a reasonable chance of being helpful to others facing
>   the same problem? If so, it's a safe bet that the question *is not*
>   too broad!

Based on this, I would really like to see a limited version of this suggestion implemented. In particular, if a question in the close review queue has an accepted answer, it would be very convenient if that answer was displayed under the question. This doesn't cover every case, of course; but more often than not, it's a useful piece of information to have when considering a review.

Also, I especially feel that now is a good time to consider implementing this; I think the recent review count changes and review queue community event will lead to a lot of people enthusiastically blowing through the queue, maybe it's best to make it as convenient as possible for people to get more information that may lead to a "Leave Open" choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think animuson has it right (in the comment to the question), there should be a way to expand to see the answers if one wanted to.  We could use a link, or and arrow (like in the mod tools) or whatever, but instead of immediately showing the answers, the reviewer would click on something to bring them up.  There are many times you don't need the answers, so this will save a bit on bandwidth.

At the very least we should be shown that there are answers, and maybe how many of them.