# Close Queue Etiquette: Accepted Answers and "Too Broad" and "Unclear what you're asking" Questions

Tags: discussion, review, etiquette

Recently, during our whole push to burn down the close queue, I came around a good load of questions that were flagged for "Too broad" or "Unclear what you're asking" - but also already answered and had accepted an answer.

While I could generally still see that the question was either too broad for our format or not really clear, I wonder what the general consensus is here? It might be a bit too broad for our minds, but somebody else could and has answered it successfully?

Sorry if this is a well establish thing - but I couldn't find any info on it.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223454/do-too-broad-questions-become-less-broad-after-an-acceptable-answer-is-given?rq=1

Comment: Ah, thanks - my search didn't turn that one up!

Comment: I'm not claiming that that answers your question... it is not a dup IMHO.

Comment: But it goes into the same direction, so it helps :)