# Timestamps missing year and time

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, timestamps, date-format

I've noticed a few posts (and it is only a few—maybe a handful) which are missing the year and time from the timestamp—The year is replaced with `\yy` and the time is replaced with `AM`/`PM`.

The timestamp shows as expected in the revision log (in the app) and everywhere on the site.

For example: two answers on [this Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223454/307988)

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

[This Science Fiction & Fantasy question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14476/68153)

> [image]

---

- App Version: 1.6.0.7
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.8.

The problem presents itself on posts more than 330 days old where users have a lot of badges.  The view sees that there isn't enough room for both the reputation and the date so it attempts to shrink it down using the mini date formatter. `5m ago` rather than `5 min ago`.  Since it's so old it uses a normal date formatter which should be the same as the normal date formatter but it is only used in this case so I didn't notice I failed to fix it when I was working out the correct date format string.

Anyway, NSDateFormatter escapes blocks of text with single quotes like `parsed 'ignored' parsed`.  To get a single quote, [you just do `blah '' blah'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059118/cant-put-a-single-quote-before-the-year-in-nsdateformatter), not `blah \\' blah` like I had tried.

Also, I'm going to go ahead and shrink the reputation and badges in this case so the date doesn't get truncated.

> [image: Screenshot showing truncation.]