# issue with an audit in the low quality review queue

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

While I was in the review queue for low quality posts, I was given an audit:

[Open a popup containing ASPX postback result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824300/using-javascript-open-a-popup-containing-aspx-postback-result)

> I have an aspx page with many fields that generate a PDF documents when I click a "export to pdf" button.
>
> I'd now like to have a "print pdf" button that does something like this : `w=window.open(?);w.print();w.close();` where `"?"` will perform the same postback as my "export to pdf" button.

I failed the audit when I attempted to flag/close this question. The question does not seem to me to be a good fit as it does not go into any detail of what the problem the poster is experiencing, nor what effort s/he's taken to get to this point.

Please guide me as to why I am mistaken in my feeling on this post!

Comment: I think the upvotes on the post made the queue recognise it as valid.

Comment: Upvotes did it, I have no idea how a post like that got that many updates though.

Comment: I'd like to plug [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) here, but it currently only [shows answers to questions in the *close vote* review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue). Shouldn't be hard to fix, though, I just need to tweak one regex and test it to make sure nothing breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question is fine but to fully grasp it you need to understand how asp.net pages work and how window.open works.

> I have an aspx page with many fields that generate a PDF documents
>   when I click a "export to pdf" button.

Basically tells that a html form is POSTed

> I'd now like to have a "print pdf" button that does something like
>   this : w=window.open(?);w.print();w.close(); where "?" will perform
>   the same postback as my "export to pdf" button.

Asks how you can still POST the data while you only can perform a GET (because that is what `window.open` does) and in asp.net it is not trivial to change a page to handle GETs instead of POSTs

To me it explains clearly what the OP has, what he needs, what he tried.

The OP didn't use too much context and I would have preferred a code sample to illustrate the issue. Despite that the question is clear and answerable for me.

For questions that are not tagged in your comfort zone *skip* might be a better option...
Or use a [filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149380/158100) as suggested by  [Ilmari Karonen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174699/ilmari-karonen) with the added benefit that audits are a little easier to spot...

Comment: ...and I'd normally recommend just [filtering the queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208287/allow-direct-linking-to-a-filtered-review-queue) to only give you questions on topics you're familiar with, but due to the way audits are currently implemented, you're still going to get random questions for those, just with faked tags. Does make them somewhat easier to spot, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I edited that in, tnx!

Answer (score 4):

First, a couple of points:

1. "Demonstration of effort" is not a good metric for closing a question.  I know that the community feels this is a requirement for asking questions on Stack Overflow, but it isn't.
2. Stack Overflow questions don't have to encompass a *problem,* in the sense of "I have this problem with this code, how do I fix it?"  ...even though that is the form that most Stack Overflow questions take.

That said, I found the question unclear, though it is apparent that the answerer did not.  Sometimes this happens; the right person shows up at the right time with a working crystal ball (or the correct expertise), and is able to divine the correct meaning from the question.