# Tricked by Audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing the queues for the first time and was asked to evaluate the accepted answer for the question below, as an audit:

*[NameError even with a direct, unconditional assignment on the line above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297921/nameerror-even-with-a-direct-unconditional-assignment-on-the-line-above)*

Of course I didn't know it was an audit (I didn't even know they existed), and I was very intrigued by the answer.  I opened the question page, as part of my investigation on it (I think the review mentioned there were other answers, so I wanted to compare).  There, I found an answer with the exact same response, by someone who was not a first-time user.

I clicked on the down vote, then, to which the page responded with the "STOP! Look and Listen." warning.

My line of thought was that someone was trying to trick the system, by adding a copy of a valid answer, so they'd get past the 'first post' audits.  If the reviewer does not open the original page to look for other answers, they may even up vote the fake answer.

That would be a very easy way to automatically get past that kind of audit, as it is easy to programmatically get the accept answer and resubmit it.

Perhaps Stack Exchange already have that kind of verification on its code, but I was surprised by the behavior.

So, my question is twofold:

- Should we be concerned by this kind of attack on the audit system, or are there already builtin protections for it?
- Is the current implementation the best interface for that kind of audit?  I think my concern was valid.  I didn't lose reputation points or anything, but it did look 'unfair' :)

Note. I'm not sure why I did the downvote, instead of flag. I'm not sure if the flag option was available, as that would make more sense.

Comment: After entering my question, I found this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266394/review-audit-failed-when-late-answer-answer-is-a-duplicate, which is very similar to mine.  That question author's concern is rep harvesting, while mine is audit spoofing.  Not sure if I should remove my question or mark it as a dup

Comment: Our FAQ on the topic, [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work), mentions this exact specific case. tl;dr you don't need to do anything *unless* you end up banned from reviewing, in which case you should post on the per-site meta and hope the moderators lift your review ban.

Comment: I've always been bothered by the use of "expected" votes in this way, as most other guidance indicates that I can vote any way I like as long as I do not target specific users.

Comment: @RobertColumbia The point of the audits is just to make sure people aren't *mindlessly* reviewing. Audits are only enabled on sites with a history of people incorrectly reviewing things, and are in fact disabled on the majority of sites.

Comment: I do not agree with this post being marked as a duplicate of the FAQ.  Yes the FAQ does answer my question, but then in the middle of a lot of other stuff.  Needle in haystack, IMO.  If it was to be marked as a dup, I'd mark it as a dup of the one I mentioned on my first comment, which is similar and as specific as mine.  Even then, I'd say mine has a different perspective, as I mentioned before, but I'd be nitpicking.  That said, I'm also sorry I cannot add my own response, after having reviewed the FAQ and that other question.  So I'll put it in a comment, for the benefit of future users

Comment: 1 - the system has some flaws.  We know it, and we're ok with it.  2 - Even if we said your review was incorrect, we're glad you reviewed it the way you did.  3 - This is a known situation, explained in the FAQ.  See next post for more info.  4 - this is a known situation (since 2015, at least), but not a known issue, as we don't think it is an issue.  5 - No harm done: you did not lose rep points or anything.  If you fail too many audits, you may be suspended from the reviews, but that's all 6 - There are ways to recognize audits, but, hey, don't you have anything better to do?

Comment: Piece of the FAQ that responds the question: "*You identify a post as being an exact duplicate of an older, highly-voted post. To prevent audits from being obvious, the vote count is displayed as zero and the user card is either anonymized or shown as having been posted by a new user. This may make you think you are looking at an exact duplicate.*"