# Show answers in close queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, user-interface

I think the new "Lifejacket" and "Lifeboat" badges are great, as they reward people who can figure out good answers to poorly phrased questions, as well as helping make the community more welcoming.  Right now, however, the structure of the close queue is still fighting against this idea.

I often find that when going through the close queue, my opinion that "this piece of junk should be closed" is reversed when I go and look at the answers and find that somebody has figured out the key issue that was obscured in the original asking. This then causes me to focus on editing the question rather than closing it, which aligns well with the "Lifejacket"/"Lifeboat" intent.

To do this, however, I find that I have to maintain a double-queue: I open the close queue and then I open the questions I'm reviewing in another tab in order to see their answers.

**Can we please have the answers (or at least the top voted and/or accepted answer) shown in the close review queue?**

Notes:

- [This has been requested in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue) and apparently partially implemented, but certainly isn't here now.
- This might be warranted in other review queues too (e.g., first questions), but the close queue is the one that I most encounter it in.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to read the answers, just click through to the question.  Then go back and review.

On a site with review audits enabled, this is worth doing in any case because you'll never get stung by a bad audit if you first have a look at the actual question and answers.

Comment: That's what I do, but a) it's an extra layer of friction, and b) I suspect that many others do not. Thus, this request.