# Duplicates of duplicates should be remapped

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I noticed today another example of *duplicates of duplicates*: that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067164/confusion-about-interface-thread) (A) was closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066006/confusion-about-thread) (B), but one day later (B) was closed as duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392052/what-is-an-anonymous-inner-class) (C). Sometimes I need to click many times from one question to another until I get to the *master* question.

I think that it's better if the question (A) is closed as duplicate of (C), and even if (B) has already (helpful) answers, (B) and (C) could be merged.

Is it possible to remap all duplicates to the *master* question, just like the tag synonyms?

Comment: in a current model, [duplication is not required to be exact](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773 "'No argument about how exact...'"); as a result, [duplicate-of is not a transitive property](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5898/31260 "as discussed here in more details") => proposed re-mapping could do more harm than good

Comment: Or we can list all the related duplicates (in yellow box), so user can choose one which suits the best, instead of keep clicking back and forth.

Answer (score 10):

No.

I have purposely voted to close a question as a duplicate of a question that was closed as a duplicate. Probably done that at least 5+ times. Probably mostly/only on meta sites though.

Why? Because I felt that either the question that I was pointing to as dup was incorrectly marked as a duplicate of the "main dup". So by choosing to close as a dup of the "main" one it wouldn't really be a dup. Also, there have been times where I felt the closed dup I was pointing to was much more an exact dup than the "main dup".

Also, when searching for help with my problems, I want to see all the dups. This would suck to just go to the main dup since I'd rather see them all naturally how they occurred in the wild.

Please don't implement this.

Comment: Closing question A as a duplicate of B will always put A on the `Linked` sidebar of B, so your last point is rather odd. In terms of connectivity, pointing all duplicates to a single main one will give you a single point of reference from which to explore the set of duplicates.