# What is the proper procedure for cleaning up a community FAQ?

Tags: discussion, meta, meta-faq

I've been in the process of going through some of our [community FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and cleaning them up, as well as reorganizing the index to make it easier to find relevant topics. In an effort to get users the information they want rather than scanning through a five-answer discussion with similar or controversial answers scattered about, I've decided that the *best* way to present a FAQ is with one answer, adding more if the extra room is required.

> **TL;DR** Our FAQs need canonical answers and, after writing them, I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to post these canonical answers. Skip down to "**What do I do now?**"

---

Here is the "new FAQ criteria" I plan to go by:

> #### What makes a good FAQ entry?
>
> Just because something gets asked frequently doesn't mean it would make a good entry in the FAQ index. The community FAQ is meant to contain canonical, definitive information about a topic to help users out, not make them ask more questions. Generally, all FAQ entries should be support questions. If your question ends up being a discussion, further consider whether it would make a good FAQ entry.
>
> Here are some general criteria which might disqualify a FAQ entry:
>
> - Having a low number of views is a good indication that this is not a topic that comes up frequently with users and therefore should not be something that we keep in the FAQ index.
> - Having a large number of answers can indicate that the answer to the question is not well-defined and the question would not be very useful to users who might stumble upon it. Most FAQ entries should only contain a single answer which can be updated by users with new or relevant information. Multiple answers, especially those which offer differing opinions, will only serve to confuse users looking to it for guidance and information.
> - Having little to no information may indicate that the FAQ entry covers too narrow of a subject.

My primary concern going through some of these is the second bullet point. I've been putting a lot of emphasis on that one because the more answers we have in a FAQ, the less useful it is to future visitors. A FAQ is *supposed* to be a one-stop place to get definitive information on site function and policy, not for a user to read through a long discussion on "maybe this, maybe that." They'll leave that FAQ with just as many questions as they went into it with, and might end up asking another question on Meta for clarity - but that's what the FAQ is meant for - to answer their question right then and there so they *don't have to ask another one*. We're kind of failing at that goal.

Following this, some of the FAQs can be quite easy. The top-voted answer will usually have all the relevant information needed to convey the message we need to get to the user searching for that information; the others can just be deleted. However, some questions can be a bit trickier.

As an example, take this [FAQ about the acceptability of duplicate answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). There's a lot of good information in there, yes. But it's also scattered through four different answers, as well as some comments under those answers. That FAQ could really use some love, and I've written a good, canonical answer that combines all the information into one place, and could serve as the single answer to the FAQ entry to answer any future visitor's questions about the subject.

---

### What do I do now?

1. Post a new answer myself and delete the others after some (unknown) length of time? The new canonical answer *was* written by me, but the question is also a community wiki so that doesn't mean all that much. However, this does let us scope out what the community thinks of the new answer by having its own vote count.
2. Edit the top-voted answer with the canonical information and delete the others? Then you run into the problem of "that's *technically* not close to what I actually voted for, but I doubt anyone would care. This has the opposite problem of point one, in that it's not *my* answer. More often this option is reserved for cases where you're just adding in additional information, rather than rewriting it.
3. Start a new [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) question in order to replace the current one? Seems like a bit of a stretch when the current one has some votes to go with it, but I'm open to the ideas of the community.

* *Note that my options are kind of specific to me being a moderator. Feel free to suggest solutions that a regular user could utilize if they wish to help in cleaning up any FAQs that are a bit of a mess.*

**Other questions to ask:**

- Should there be some sort of a note at the top of the canonical answer, explaining its intentions (at least until the others get deleted)?
- How long would we wait before deleting the other answers?

Comment: You could post a support question that contains your answer asking whether you should post your answer and delete the others. People can then suggest edits to your answer in a frenzy of meta-meta-meta-ness (one more?) or downvote you to oblivion if they think your replacement is crap :-). There's a small chance of the opposite happening of course :-)

Comment: P.S., new question is not really an option as questions [don't inherit the "frequent" power of the questions that got closed as a duplicate of it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202483/questions-should-inherit-their-duplicates-frequent-power)

Comment: I would first post your consolidated answer as a new answer, with a small highlighted banner at the top of the answer explaining what you are doing, so we can see what kind of votes it gets.  If it is received well, we can delete the other answers, and maybe get Will to move the check mark.

Comment: That said, in the past I have been bold, edited the checkmarked answer into shape, and deleted all the other answers, if I was confident that it accurately represented the community consensus.  If your answer is good, maybe we can get it reviewed by a couple of other mods, and just get it done.  FAQ questions are not meant to be discussion platforms; they are *documentation of a policy.*

Answer (score 2):

If one of the top-voted answers already had the majority of the information, I encourage you to just edit all the information into that answer. If not, a new canonical answer makes more sense.

For any user wishing to help with cleaning up the FAQs, this is the notice I'm going to use at the top of my canonical answers to support voting and importing any and all relevant information:

> **FAQ Clean-up Note:** This answer is meant to help clean up this FAQ by creating a canonical answer that sums up all the information available in the question and further explaining it. Please feel free to edit in pieces of information that are missing or unclear. Eventually, other answers will be deleted.

I also wrote a separate bounty notice text to help bring attention to posts which I'm not quite sure about and don't feel I could write a good canonical answer for:

> As it currently stands, this question contains a lot of information spread out across many answers. In order to make this into a better FAQ, a canonical answer that contains *all of the relevant information* is required. Once a canonical answer can be created and voted up, other answers should be deleted in order to ensure visitors are getting a quick and concise answer to their question.

I'm still a bit iffy on the timeframe for deleting other answers (particularly the few top-voted ones), but after a canonical answer has been posted, most of the lower-scored answers and answers which don't contain much, if any, useful information should be deleted immediately. This will make for less scrolling to the canonical answer we wish to push to the top, and get rid of some of the clutter right away.