# Duplicates of poor-quality questions lacking answers

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Here's the scenario. A user asks a poor quality question that is difficult to understand, let alone answer. As a result, nobody feels confident enough to offer an answer. A few comments are made asking for clarification, but the poster doesn't provide anything useful.

Later the same user, frustrated with the lack of response, re-posts essentially the same question again. However I can't vote to close this second question as a duplicate, because the first question has no accepted or upvoted answers.

What's the best thing to do in this situation?

Comment: Tell OP to improve the first question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: If it's the same author, you should be able to vote to close it, shouldn't you? Edit: Yep [*"Second, you can always close as dupe if it's from the same user, to cover the case of problem users who post the same thing multiple times."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux).

Comment: Thanks. Actually it's a different user ID, but the wording and content is almost identical so I suspect it's the same person with multiple accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to vote to close it if it has the same problems as the original post. It doesn't have to be closed as a duplicate, it can be closed as 'unclear what you're asking' (if that's the actual problem you have with the post).

If, for some strange reason, a user re-asks a question, and the new question *has no issues with it whatsoever*, then your best bet is to leave a comment letting the user know they should edit their original question, and flag the new question for moderator attention, with something like the following:

> This user posted this question previously here (link to question).  Could you merge the two questions and delete (this/that) question because the (new/old) question is asked better?

Comment: Great advice, thanks.