# Question closed as too localized, but then closed question is cited in duplicates?

Tags: discussion, bug, close-reasons, too-localized

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3873122 is up for closure as a duplicate.

The duplicate cited is [Functions stop working when file included with root path (leading slash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239629/functions-stop-working-when-file-included-with-root-path-leading-slash), which was closed as too localized.

Someone commented that about the latter: "I honestly don't understand why this thread has been closed. This is a perfectly important programming issue affecting many non-expert programmers."

It seems to me a question being cited as too localized and "unlikely to help any future visitors" should not be cited for future visitors. Or the too localized question should be reopened.

(Sorry, I had to use "bug" tag because "possible-bug" was not available to me).

Comment: Looks like the "too localised" question is well on its way to reopening

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case, I agree 100%.  If a question is a duplicate of something, then "Too Localized" would not seem to apply as it is helpful to someone else.  That being said, if there is no bug here as the system is working as designed.  You can close a question as a duplicate regardless of the closed status of the question.

---

This would seem to be more of a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) since you want to change how the system works.

Making a specific rule to prevent "Too Localized" questions from being the duplicate target would be a waste of time since "Too Localized" has been depreciated, although we do have a similar custom close reason now.  If you encounter one, it is best just to leave a comment as to why you think it should be reopened, and then vote to reopen (if you have the privileges) or flag the post to reopen it.

But in a broader sense, even though questions are closed, they can still have value so preventing duplicate closure of closed question is not appropriate.  There are a number of closed questions with good answers.  There is also often good feedback in the comments as to why the question is closed and/or suggestions on how to resolve the problem.

So closing new questions as duplicates of closed questions can help point users to specific solutions that already exist.  This is the entire point of duplicates.  Likewise, questions can be closed for another reason **after** being the target of a duplicate closure, so any prohibition would end up failing here unless you prevent closure to begin with.

The real issue is closing a question as a duplicate of any question that does not have an answer (regardless of whether it is closed or not) and fortunately the system now requires a question to have an up-voted or accepted answer before it can be used as the target of a duplicate question.<sup>1</sup>

This was not always the case though, so if you do see a question closed as a duplicate of an unanswered question, especially a closed unanswered question, you should flag the question to get reopened and closed as a better duplicate or closed for the appropriate reason.

<sup>1</sup> - Meta sites are exempt from this requirement because duplicates are often used to prevent multiple unresolved bug reports or duplicate feature requests from splitting the discussion.

Comment: Another exempt seems to be made if both questions are asked by the same user.

Comment: @Mołot Yes, you are right, but I think it is more specific than - I think it takes into account time posted as well, and might also consider how similar the questions are.

Answer (score 0):

If question is a duplicate, then it is a duplicate and should be closed as such.

If original question is closed:

1. If needed, edit it into shape, to make it meet current criteria. If it already does, comment.
2. Flag / vote for reopening.

Your concern is pretty void as bugreport, as "too localised" close reason is long gone. No questions will earn it. It is only seen on old closed questions, but it was decided it should not be. Who are we to decide what will be useful for future visitors and what will not? So don't expect any special handling for them.

Comment: Mołot - iIf original question is closed, edit it into shape as needed and flag / vote for reopening." - Two problems here. One, the question looks good to me but I'm not an expert at PHP. So I should not be voting on it (in this case I did , however). Second, it should not be closed as "too localized" and then used for future visitors because its not supposed to help future visitors. Somethings clearly bent for the second point.

Comment: @noloader "too localised" was removed for a reason, and questions like this was the reason.

Comment: @noloader answer updated to make it more clear - I admit what I wrote might not be exactly what I meant. I'm doing my best...

Comment: Mołot - no problems. There's no wrong doing, and there's no need to apologize.

Answer (score -2):

I dislike the feature of questions closed as duplicate of closed question. The idea of closing as duplicate is **pointing out** to other questions. What's the value of pointing out to something that is closed because it wasn't good enough?

In my opionion

1. It shouldn't be possible to vote to close something as a duplicate of closed questions
2. If the question is closed, any close votes poiting to it as duplicate should be invalidated
3. If question A is closed as duplicate of B, and B gets closed for any reason, there should be some automatic action, for example reopen vote, to allow community to handle such situation.

Please **don't show that question is a duplicate of closed question!** It doesn't make sense!

Comment: I'm not sure why your observations and opinions are being down voted. They make perfect sense to me, especially considering this question has a "discussion" tag.

Comment: I strongly disagree. On Drupal Answers there are a lot of duplicates of "Why is Drupal slow?". It's faster to close them as duplicates than to repeat the discussion about how such questions are bad again and again and again... Askers can see the original comments exchange, and (useful) answers posted before original question was closed.

Comment: Mołot - does "duplicate" have the transitivity property? That is, if *A* is the original question, and *B* is a duplicate of *A*, and *C* is a duplicate of *B*, can the site make *C* a duplicate of *A*? That way, any similar closed will suffice and lead bak to the original question.

Comment: @Mołot I think you are misusing the close vote. You should close as duplicate only then, when the original question is or can be answered by linked question. Otherwise, it should be closed with correct close reason.

Comment: @noloader in a current model, ["duplicate" does **not** have the transitivity property](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5898/31260 "discussed in more details here")

Comment: Thanks @gnat. Is that a design decision (forgive me for asking)?

Comment: @ŁukaszL. In case of "why is Drupal slow", duplicate questions **are** answered by answers under closed original one. And even if they weren't, is there any reason to close them with other reason, and when original gets reopened (if ever), then reopen them all just to close them as duplicates? Why to bother with so much of a pointless work?

Comment: @noloader design decision was to [define duplication](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773) this way. As for transitivity, it simply follows that, it was not considered worth worrying about at all