# Duplicate question from same user, neither one has answers

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

What should I do if I see that a user has posted the exact same problem multiple times? Neither of the questions have answers, so I can't flag the latter one as a duplicate of the first one. Is it okay if I flag it for moderator attention?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions from the same user are an exception to the "you can't close as duplicate of a question with no answers" rule. It's precisely for the situation you describe: an Asker has (inadvertently or with intent) posted the same question multiple times.

You should be able to vote to close one as a duplicate of the other even without the target having answers. If you can't (perhaps because the user has created multiple user accounts) then you should flag for Moderator attention.

See also: [Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/21960)