# When closing a question as a duplicate of a duplicate, automatically link to the non-duplicate question

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

I've just stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66065495/7233423) and was surprised to see it closed as a duplicate of an [already closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13763942/7233423).

First of all, declaring a question as a duplicate of a closed question seems weird to me. But what is weirder, is that this other question was itself closed as a duplicate of a [third question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2746553/7233423).

Logically, the first question should have been closed as a duplicate of the third one. Somehow, linking to the second question seems to implies it is not really a duplicate of the third one.

I'm wondering why this situation is allowed to happen. Questions closed as duplicates should not be suggested to voters. When closing as a duplicate of a duplicate, I believe the underlying software should follow the list of duplicates and directly point to the last question in the list, i.e. the one that is not closed.

Comment: It's allowed because on Meta, it's enough that existing answer also answers a different question and that question might be closed as duplicate, **even if it asked something else**. Hard to explain, I'll try to think of something more clear and post as answer. Anyway, the idea is good, and many times high rep user with dupe hammer does exactly this, i.e. adding link to the root, but it's manual and not automatic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Shadow. Actually, I can't help thinking that, if the second question should be preferred over the third one, then the second one should be reopened (and maybe the third one should then be closed as a duplicate of the second one).

Comment: In the long wrong we risk crashing our browsers by opening too many tabs chasing the original duplicate target.

Comment: @bad_coder Crashing your browser? Heck, I've got 63 tabs open!

Comment: related: [Marking question as duplicate of duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268485/839601) at MSO

Comment: Thanks @gnat, this is helpful. In the [linked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/348535) there is an enlightening sentence: "The fundamental goal of dupes is to help people find the right answer by getting all of the answers in one place. It is not to just clean up clutter.". I also notice that some suggest in comments the same thing as this request.

Comment: I see this request being downvoted. Is it a way to show a disagreement with the feature request, or rather to tell me that I didn't search enough? (actually I did spend a fair amount of time here looking for an answer and I finally decided to open this FR)

Comment: Related: [Duplicates of duplicates?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6933/70545) at PSE

Comment: @Nai45, Amateurs, despite saying [∞] it's [only some 500+ tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyVIr.png).

Comment: @Rob I am in awe.

Comment: @Rob Is that your browser frequently?

Comment: "then the second one should be reopened" - no, it shouldn't. Both are duplicates of a third, each in a different way. Still need to think this up and post answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Owing to Ann Zen's answer and the links in comment above, I now have a good understanding of why linking to a duplicate is possible and considered valid. Judging by the score of this question, it seems like what I deemed logical is considered here as a very bad idea, so I'm not sure it's worth the time that you write your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea.

One reason I've seen questions getting marked as a duplicate of a duplicate is how the question relates to the duplicate more than the non-duplicate.

On Stack Overflow *(that's the site you are referring to in your post)*, sadly, it is **very common for a post to be closed as a duplicate of another post for being ever so *slightly* related**, causing issues, of course. For example, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPbynQsdl24&t=3m55s)'s my favorite rant ^^

I'm not saying that's the case with the posts you linked, I'm saying that it would be **better to allow users to mark questions as duplicates of the posts that are the most related**, even if that post is a duplicate of another post.

Also, when searching for a problem, I'd much **prefer to have many pages to research on, instead of a single page**, as there will be a high chance that the issue proposed in that post would have at least a single element that I don't have, causing the whole thread of answers to be useless for me. With more links of posts of the "same" problem, I'll have many more posts to resort to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tend to agree with what you write except "I'd much prefer to have many pages to research on, instead of a single page". I understand this is your preference but I can't help but think this should not be imposed to the users. After all, it somehow defeats the purpose of "closing as dupe" which leads people to answer on a single page. Personally, I do not want to follow a long thread of duplicates, but this is just my preference.

Comment: @xhienne As stated in my post, *"There will be a high chance that the issue proposed in that post would have at least a single element that I don't have, causing the whole thread of answers to be useless."* If that were the case, an answer that would actually solve another user's problem will have to say something like *"If that `div` tag were at the very bottom of the page, then the answer is..."*, which is not productive to add to the original post.

Comment: Oh, sorry if I misread you. In the example I give, that led me to react here, the issue is much more trivial. The first question raises a very common problem which is perfectly answered in any of the two other questions, but I'm expecting to find better answers in the question that is still opened. Anyway, I get your point and I tend to agree now. Shall I delete this request then?

Comment: @xhienne *"Shall I delete this request then?"* No, that would be counterproductive. Leave this post to inform future readers.

Comment: @xhienne, `"Questions closed as duplicates should not be suggested to voters. and ..."`, as Ann has pointed out, the ***one*** (up to **5**) linked to in the banner *is* the one (or more) chosen by the reviewers as approximately the closest; and not necessarily others *further down the line*. Also, the ***one*** linked to *could* have up to 5 suggested duplicates, and the best course of action **is** to go *one deep*; where if only one link were chosen to terminate the list an *exploration* of related information could be cut short. --- The right column lists these interrelationships.